# dynamic sql passing parameter of length > 8000

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am creating a report that may allow for the user to select All Codes in the database.  When this is converted to a string, it passes a string with more than 8000 characters.  Since this is a parameter, I am not sure how to split this.  I am using Sql Server 2008 and have tried the varchar(max) as well.

Comment: what is the error you get ? r u using asp.net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a **VERY BAD** practice storing a list in DB string (varchar) variable.
But, if you absolutely must do it for some external independent reasons than CLOB is the thing for you.
But still I suggest you try to rethink the concept.

BTW: you can always pass a "shortcut" code like **ALL** (or any other special meaning code word) in such situations instead...

Comment: Thanks, I passed a shortcut code so as not to pass such a long parameter.